# MySQL full text search for words with three or less letters

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to get my full text search (in boolean mode) to retrieve words with three letters or less.

Currently, if I search for something like "NBA", I don't get any results.

However, if I append the wild card operator "*" to the search term, I get results.

I also read that you could remove the three word limit in `my.ini`, but I'm wondering if there was a better way to do this on the fly.

Answer (score 18):

This section of the manual might interest you : [11.8.6. Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) *(quoting a portion of it)* :

> The minimum and maximum lengths of
>   words to be indexed are defined by the
>   `ft_min_word_len` and `ft_max_word_len`
>   system variables. The
>   default minimum value is four
>   characters; the default maximum is
>   version dependent. If you change
>   either value, you must rebuild your
>   FULLTEXT indexes. 
> For example, if you
>   want three-character words to be
>   searchable, you can set the
>   `ft_min_word_len` variable by putting
>   the following lines in an option file:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> ft_min_word_len=3
> ```
>
> Then you must restart the server and
>   rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

*(You should read that page, for more informations I didn't copy-paste ;-) )*

Comment: Thanks Pascal, 

I read the same already, the idea I have is to do it with a PHP function that checks the length of the search phrase and appends the wildcard * modifier if it is less than ft_min_word_len
wondering if there is a better way to go about it than that...

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't understand that ;; I don't have much of an idea about that... not sure it would be good performance wise, though ;; just as a sidenote : what about using some external indexing/searching engine, like solr or sphinx ?

Comment: thanks, 

I've heard of sphinx but haven't had the time to wrap my head around it yet, will look into it soon