# Fulltext search on mysql with a 3 letter word

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to find "the zen" string in a field containing "The Zen Circus".
I've got a FULLTEXT index.

```
select url,name,
,   MATCH(name) AGAINST ( 'zen*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as A
,   MATCH(name) AGAINST ( '"the zen*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as B
,   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('>the* zen' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as C
,   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('thezen*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as D
,   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('cir*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as E
,   MATCH(name) AGAINST ('circus*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as F
from pages where url='thezencircus'
```

I've got this result:

```
url = thezencircus
name = The Zen Circus
A = 0   (why?)
B = 0   (why?)
C = 0   (why?)
D = 0   (ok)
E = 1   (ok)
F = 1   (ok)
```

I've also putted ft_min_word_len = 2 in the msyql config file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this answer [MySQL full text search for words with three or less letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585611/mysql-full-text-search-for-words-with-three-or-less-letters)

> [mysqld]
>   ft_min_word_len=3
>   Then you must restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

Remeber to restart and rebuild indexes.

---

**Edit**
Run `show variables like 'ft_%';` to confirm that the word length matches what you set it to.

Comment: I've done everything you said, thank you, but the problem is still here. :-(

Comment: Try running REPAIR TABLE pages QUICK; Also, just to make sure you got it right, on setting the ft_min_word_length: http://lostquery.com/questions/196/how-do-i-enable-short-3-letter-full-text-search-in-mysql is this how you did it?

Comment: Also, see my edit on how to confirm the value of the ft_min_word_len

Comment: Stupid! It works! thank you for the support, the server was not restarted (the hosting provider told me he did it, but he didn't!)

Answer (score 2):

Kao is right but that didn't help me at all - why? InnoDB table uses a different setting - try updating this one and checking it with:

```
    show variables like 'innodb_ft_min_token_size';
```

Comment: Yep, that was my issue.  ft_min_word_len was already set to 2 before I even created my indexes, but setting innodb_ft_min_token_size as well and then restarting the server and deleting and recreating the index worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST('$aranan*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM vod WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$aranan*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).