# Full Text Search MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I Know how to use 'full text search MySQL'. What i want to know is how to search text for words . For exmaple :- We have three records in mysql as following

1.) This is a place for programmers .
2.) People visit places for travelling purposes.
3.) programmers visit this place site for coding purposes.

Now When A user searches for 'place for programmers'

Following should be the output 
it should output rows that contain all words from the sentence in any order

1.)This is a **place for programmers**.
2.)**programmers** visit this **place** site **for** coding purposes.

Thank You For Helping .

Comment: You can try looking only for the first word, then look for the second in the results, and so forth.

Comment: try your full text search in boolean mode

Comment: Could you please put your answer in form of a SQL query , that would help a lot

Comment: actually fulltext search will probably ignore the word 'for', so that wont really work.

Comment: I just did experimented it with twitter and it is producing the desired results ...How do they do it?

Comment: @user3578478 Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to upvote answers that were helpful to you, and mark as the 'accepted answer' the one that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

1. Before using the full text search, index the columns

   ```
   ALTER TABLE <table> ADD FULLTEXT(column);
   ```
2. Verify that it already in Full Text

   ```
   SELECT 
       index_name, group_concat(column_name) as columns
   FROM 
       information_Schema.STATISTICS 
   WHERE 
       table_schema = 'your_db_name' 
       AND table_name = 'table_name'
       AND index_type = 'FULLTEXT'
   GROUP BY 
       index_name;
   ```
3. Then use following SQL

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM <table>
   WHERE MATCH(<column>) AGAINST('+place +for +programmers' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has MATCH..AGAINST for full text searches. Try the following,

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE MATCH(<column>) AGAINST('+place +for +programmers' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The +'s basically mean AND (you could use - for OR)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: And also you have to add a full text index in the column

Comment: I just tried it in mysql phpmyadmin i created a random table and populated  it with the same above rows , and tried the query , But it is returning empty set of reults

Comment: What is the schema for the random table?

Comment: that wont work due to the presence of `+for`. if you want to look for the three letter words, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049306/fulltext-search-on-mysql-with-a-3-letter-word). also, the boolean searches are `or` by default, `+` in front of a word means `and`. `-` in front of a word means `not`, not `or` as is stated in the answer

Comment: Thank You So Much , i just fixed it and now it works perfectly.. Thank You So Much!!!!